# sql conditional union on rowcount

Tags: sql

I have an SQL function which returns a list of Teams.

I want to join an additional list to that list with a union, but only if first select returns more than one rows.

Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Teams()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
  SELECT * FROM TABLE1
  if @@rowcount>1      
  UNION 
  SELECT * FROM TABLE2
  end if
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly

```
CREATE FUNCTION Teams()
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
( 
  if (select COUNT(*) from TABLE2)>1  
   SELECT * FROM TABLE1
   UNION 
   SELECT * FROM TABLE2
  else
   SELECT * FROM TABLE1
 )
```

Comment: That seems to be what I want, but I wanted to avoid making the same select twice (one for count and one to get the result)..

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty but this should work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Teams() 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN 
( 
  SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
  UNION  
  SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE1)
 )
```

If the select from the first table is complicated you could put it into a CTE:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Teams() 
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN 
( 
  WITH Result AS
  (
      SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ComplicatedConditions = 1
  )
  SELECT * FROM Result
  UNION  
  SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Result)
 )
```

Comment: I don't know why, but this doesn't seem to work.. Could you please check again?

Comment: As you guessed, the select of Table1 has really complicated conditions.. So, something like that, would be perfect!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to do:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1)
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM TABLE2
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1
```